# Is my password secure?

Tags: code-golf, string, classification

## Task:

Take a string as input and if it meets the requirements, accept the password.

**Input**: a string, e.g. `someString`, `asjk23t89h`, `123456789abcdef`.

**Output**: two distinct values representing "secure" and "insecure", e.g. `0`/`1`, `true`/`false`, `secure`/`insecure`.

## Password requirements:

In order for a password to be determined as secure, it must:

- Be at least 8 characters in length.
- Contain at least one character each from the four groups `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `!"£$%^&*()_+-={}[]:@~;'#<>?,./`

## Examples:

- `password`    -> insecure
- `password123` -> insecure
- `L0h~[/1s7C`  -> secure
- `h&fn3*#`     -> insecure
- `C#de g07F`   -> secure

## Winning:

This is code golf, the shortest answer wins.

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6203/security-by-post-it)

Comment: Can you clarify the "ASCII symbol" part? Do you mean any non-letter, non-digit ASCII character (including spaces, linefeeds, and other control characters)? Or do you mean printable/non-whitespace ASCII only? Also what range of characters can appear in the input in the first place?

Comment: Did you add a non-ASCII character (`£`) to the list intentionally?

Comment: "Is my password secure?" `s->"no"` (7 bytes answer in Java \o/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Java 8, <s>93</s> <s>62</s> <s>65</s> 60 bytes

```java
s->s.matches("([a-z]()|[A-Z]()|\\d()|.()){8,}+\\2\\3\\4\\5")
```

+3 bytes due to a bugfix, pointed out by *@MartinEnder♦*.
-5 bytes thanks to *@jaytea* by using capture groups instead of lookaheads, since the matches are not overlapping.

Old answer with (redundant) dictionary (**<s>93</s> 96 bytes**):

```java
d->s->!d.contains(s.toLowerCase())&s.matches("(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[\\W_]).{8,}")
```

<s>Because I can't think of a single word in the dictionary that contains at least one uppercase, lowercase, digit and other ASCII character.. So the dictionary-check is kinda redundant in that case.</s>

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jY/BTsMwEETv@YpVKiEbiGkbUJEikFAlTtBLb2R7cG23cUnsKHaLoIRfT13IPVxmtdqnmdkdP/DE1srs5HsnSu4cvHJtjhGANl41Gy4ULM4rwNraUnEDgix9o80WHM3CoY2COM@9FrAAAw/QueTRsYp7UShHYpLz5GtF6Hf@lLydJ6IMygilx/vr9gpxipgi3iLexbTLfsMAwqj36zK49uYHqyVUoV2fn6@A079qy0/nVcXs3rM6nHxpiGGCxHV46MM2MqY0@xc4maaD7Mu4@MlvJm42H0SLi41JL0eD3HwkFWzHs@eebKO2OwE)

```java
s->                    // Method with String parameter and boolean return-type
  s.matches("([a-z]()  //  Checks if the String contains at least one lowercase letter
             |[A-Z]()  //  and at least one uppercase letter
             |\\d()    //  and at least one digit
             .()       //  and at least one other ASCII character
             ){8,}+\\2\\3\\4\\5")
                       //  And has a length of at least 8
                       // End of method (implicit / single-line return-statement)
```

Comment: Here is a trick for golfing multiple, non-overlapping subexpressions that's shorter than using lookaheads: "([a-z]()|[A-Z]()|\d()|.()){8,}+\2\3\4\5"

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>112</s> <s>107</s> <s>83</s> 86 bytes

```python
lambda s:re.match(r'(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\W_]).{8,}',s)!=None
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqihVLzexJDlDo0hdw95WTys6UbcqVhPCdNSNgjJjUqBCMeHxsZp61RY6teo6xZqKtn75ealcmbkF@UUlCkWp/wuKMvNKFNI01AsSi4vL84tS1DW5MMQMjYyRhX0MMuqi9Q2LzZ2RRTPU0vKMtZSRhZyVU1IV0g3M3dQ1/wMA)

Comment: You can remove the `!=None` as the match will either return a truthy or falsey value (a match object or `None`)